# Facebook graph api user access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been working on a website which use public facebook information such as posts.

There are few important things i'd like to emphasize :

- User access token is definitely different from app access token
- I'm not building a facebook app , but a site which uses facebook public information.

The problem comes up when I use a certain user access token , and about half an hour later I can not use this access token anymore becuase it has expired.

I'd like to know how am i able to get a permanent or at least a long term user access token ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set when it expires. However the auth token should be extended whenever you need it and it has expired. The reason it's short is probably for security.

(I've only worked with the iOS SDK but I assume it follows the same principle)

Comment: The fact that is short for security reasons is not helpful for solving my problem , I need to know how to get at least a  long term access token

Comment: That's not all I said was it? I did some reading however and if you fetch a token from a Oauth call it will be valid for 60 days (graphpath "/Oauth/access_token/"). There's alot of good information about this one easy google search away.